# How do I use 'and' statement within 'ifelse' statement in mutate?

Tags: r

I have a large csv, and there are two columns titled derived_race and derived_ethnicity.  I am trying to put them into one column titled Race.  Within the derived_race column there are multiple races including 'White', 'Black or African American', 'Asian', 'Joint', etc.  Within the derived_ethnicity column there is just 'Hispanic or Latino' and 'Not Hispanic or Latino'.  In the new column that I am creating, I am only want 4 categories - White, Black, Hispanic, and Other.

For white: the derived_Race should be 'White' and the derived ethnicity should be 'Not Hispanic or Latino'
For black: the derived_race should be 'Black or African American' and the derived_ethnicity should be 'Not Hispanic or Latino'
For Hispanic: the derived_ethnicity should be 'Hispanic or Latino'
Other should be everything else

The current code that I tried to use is:

```
 mutate(Race = ifelse(derived_race == 'Black or African American', derived_ethnicity = 'Not Hispanic or Latino', 'Black', ifelse(derived_race == 'White', derived_ethnicity == 'Not Hispanic or Latino', 'White', ifelse(derived_ethnicity == 'Hispanic or Latino', 'Hispanic', 'Other'))))
```

I think that I am using the and statements wrong.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the OP meant `==` instead of `=`, the "and" symbol is `&`

```
library(dplyr)  
df1 %>%
  mutate(Race = ifelse(derived_race == 'Black or African American' &
        derived_ethnicity == 'Not Hispanic or Latino', 'Black', 
      ifelse(derived_race == 'White' & derived_ethnicity ==
         'Not Hispanic or Latino', 'White',
       ifelse(derived_ethnicity == 'Hispanic or Latino', 'Hispanic', 'Other'))))
```

---

Or instead of a nested `ifelse`, we can use `case_when`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(Race = case_when(derived_race ==  'Black or African American' &
        derived_ethnicity == 'Not Hispanic or Latino' ~ 'Black,
    derived_race == 'White' & derived_ethnicity ==
         'Not Hispanic or Latino' ~ 'White',
      derived_ethnicity == 'Hispanic or Latino' ~ 'Hispanic', TRUE ~ 'Other'))
```